# python : joblib issues when saving and using file

Tags: python, joblib

I am parallelizing a process that first processes and cleans a dataframe, then saves the resulting dataframe to a csv (this step is necessary to be able to load the data to a database) and finally loads the csv (via staging) to the database data (snowflake).
The problem is that the csv has a fixed assigned name and is therefore shared by different threads. This causes the script to fail.
Schematically the script is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

define process_data():
      make some queries with parameter (i)
      process and clean data
      dataframe.to_csv('temp_dataframe.csv')
      stage 'temp_dataframe.csv' as 'temp_dataframe.stage'
      loads 'temp_dataframe.stage' to database

Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(process_data)(i) for i in N)
```

Any ideas about how to solve this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a different file name for each thread?

Comment: do you have to save it in file? Maybe it can use `file-like` object created in memory (using `io.StringIO` ). ie. `file_obj = io.StringIO()` and `dataframe.to_csv(file_obj)` and maybe later it can use `file_obj` to send data to database.

Comment: about "Use a different file name for each thread? – mkrieger1" ... the filename is in the function... I do not know how to dinamically assign different names to each thread ...